# RestAssured: How to check the length of json array response?

Tags: json, rest-assured

I have an endpoint that returns a JSON like:

```
[
  {"id" : 4, "name" : "Name4"},
  {"id" : 5, "name" : "Name5"}
]
```

and a DTO class:

```
public class FooDto {
    public int id;
    public String name;
}
```

Now, I'm testing the length of the returned json array this way:

```
@Test
public void test() {
    FooDto[] foos = RestAssured.get("/foos").as(FooDto[].class);
    assertThat(foos.length, is(2));
}
```

But, is there any way to do it without cast to FooDto array? Something like this:

```
@Test
public void test() {
    RestAssured.get("/foos").then().assertThat()
      .length(2);
}
```

Answer (score 79, accepted):

Solved! I have solved it this way:

```
@Test
public void test() {
    RestAssured.get("/foos").then().assertThat()
      .body("size()", is(2));
}
```

Comment: Hi, How to pass size restriction, when doing non-BDD style rest-assured. viz-     public Response putRequest() {
        httpRequest.header("Content-Type",ContentType.JSON);
        httpRequest.header("Accept",ContentType.JSON);
        httpRequest.header("Authorization", System.getProperty("apiKey"));
        return httpRequest.request(Method.PUT);
    }

Answer (score 14):

You can simply call `size()` in your body path:

Like:

```
given()
            .accept(ContentType.JSON)
            .contentType(ContentType.JSON)
            .auth().principal(createPrincipal())
            .when()
            .get("/api/foo")
            .then()
            .statusCode(OK.value())
            .body("bar.size()", is(10))
            .body("dar.size()", is(10));
```

Answer (score 9):

There are ways. I solved with the below

```
@Test
public void test() {
 ValidatableResponse response = given().when().get("/foos").then();
 response.statusCode(200);
 assertThat(response.extract().jsonPath().getList("$").size(), equalTo(2));
}
```

using restassured 3.0.0

Comment: is it possible to limit /batch the restassured response body?

Answer (score 5):

I solved similar task wit GPath.

```
Response response = requestSpec
                .when()
                .get("/new_lesson")
                .then()
                .spec(responseSpec).extract().response();
```

Now I can extract response body as String and use built-in GPath capabilities

```
String responseBodyString = response.getBody().asString();

assertThat(from(responseBodyString).getList("$").size()).isEqualTo(YOUR_EXPECTED_SIZE_VALUE);
assertThat(from(responseBodyString).getList("findAll { it.name == 'Name4' }").size()).isEqualTo(YOUR_EXPECTED_SUB_SIZE_VALUE);
```

For full example see http://olyv-qa.blogspot.com/2017/07/restassured-short-example.html

Answer (score 5):

This is what you need to do in order to get size.

```
Response response = 
given()
.header("Accept","application/json")
.when()
.get("/api/nameofresource")
.then()
.extract()
.response();
```

once you have the response, you can do the following to get the size.

int size = response.jsonPath().getList("id").size();

hope this helps. :)

Answer (score 4):

@Héctor

```
[   
   {"id" : 4, "name" : "Name4"}, 
   {"id" : 5, "name" : "Name5"}
]
```

It was really unlucky example. Here you have matrix [2,2].

If you create something like this:

```
[   
   {"id" : 4, "name" : "Name4"}, 
   {"id" : 5, "name" : "Name5"}, 
   {"id" : 6, "name" : "Name6"} 
]
```

Now you still get passed test:

```
@Test
public void test() {
    RestAssured.get("/foos").then().assertThat()
      .body("size()", is(2));
}
```

Consider about whether it was intentional. 
`body("size()",is(2));` Have checking length of one node instead of number of records in response.

Answer (score 2):

Also possible option is  `hasSize()` matcher along with `"."` path:

```
import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.hasSize;

...

@Test
public void test() {
    RestAssured.get("/foos").then().assertThat()
      .body(".", hasSize(2));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this :)**

```
   Response response = RestAssured
   .given()    
        .header("Content-Type", "application/json")    
   .when()    
        .get("api/v1/blablabla/");    
        
    int responseLength = 
    response.body().jsonPath().getList("$").size();
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).